# How to remove random number of nodes from a network graph?

Tags: python, networkx

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import pylab as pl

g = nx.read_edgelist('/home/suman/Desktop/dataset/Email-Enron.txt',
                     create_using=None, nodetype=int, edgetype=int)

n = nx.number_of_nodes(g)

print n
```

Comment: select some [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) nodes and [remove them](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_nodes_from.html)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. What have you tried?

Comment: i am trying to remove 10% of nodes from  a network dataset and then generate the new edgelist after removing nodes and then calculate assortative cofficient .                                                                                                                   how to select ramdom nodes (like 10% noes) and remove it ?                                                                                                                 here total number of node n= 36692

Comment: how to select ramdom nodes (like 10% noes) and remove it ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution, made on a small sample of data:

```
import networkx as nx
import random

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(3,4),(4,5)])

ListOfNodes = G.nodes()
NumberofNodes = G.number_of_nodes()
```

This returns as `G.nodes()`:

```
ListOfNodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Then define the sample of nodes you want to take from the total number of nodes in
your graph (here 3, in your case you can set a sample of `int(NumberofNodes*0.1)`:

```
sample = 3
RandomSample = random.sample(ListOfNodes, sample)
```

then you can remove the sample nodes from your graph with:

```
G.remove_nodes_from(RandomSample)
```

Calling back the `G.nodes()` you obtain:

```
[1, 4, 5]
```

EDIT:
There was an issue with `RandomSample = random.sample(ListOfNodes, sample)` because networkx starts node numbering from 1. Now it should work properly selecting a random `sample` of nodes directly from the node list.

Comment: thank you but here one error occour   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'random'.

Comment: Did you import random?

Comment: yeah,i  import random. but then also this error occour.    and one more question how to remove first 10 nodes from nodelist ?

Comment: Can you reproduce my example? For me it works, in case you have problem, please post your python and networkx versions.

Comment: Sorry there was an issue with the code, see edit and let me know if it works correctly. And please avoid asking more questions in the comments. Once you have solve the actual problem, consider posting a new question.

Comment: thank you so much,my problems are solve and my code are properly execute